# How can i rewrite my category url for redirect new site

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, websites

How can i configure category url rewrite management. When user click category it leads to another site.

[image]

Comment: You cannot manage it from URL Rewrites inside Magento. Either you can implement using .htaccess or server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The way you added cms page in "URL Rewrite Management" you can add external url too.

Create a category, in my case category ID is 3
Add a new URL Rewrite from URL rewrite management

Enter ID Path: category/3

Enter Request Path: catalog/category/view/id/3

Enter your external url in "Target Path"

Thanks

Comment: i can't able to edit target path

Comment: So I think first you can test it in fresh magento if there it will work then problem is in your current magento.

Comment: in fresh installation also am not able to alter target path

Comment: You can directly create menu from file and give it to external site also. But I think this is not good way in Magento so I didn't suggest.

Comment: bro, what i need is, when user click one of my category directly redirect to new site

Comment: Yes so I gave just that answer bro but I think it is not correct way that's why I didn't suggest you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45449/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-mayur).

Comment: @Mayur after reindexed the configuration back to original, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: @Mayur did you faced the error after reindexed not working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all open

**marketing --> SEO & Search --> URL Rewrites**

then after **Add URL Rewrites**

```
 1. add store
 2. Request Path
 3. Target Path
 4. Redirect Type --> NO/Temporary(302)/Permanent(301) 
 5. Description
```

[image]

Save and Check List

[image]